# How to Make a discord bot send a message in the servers that it is in?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So I'm trying to make a bot that send a message to all the servers that it is in, but the problem is that I don't really know how to make the user chose the specific channel that he wants, and that I don't know how to make the bot send a message to the servers that the bot is in. If someone could help, or tell me about a tutorial that would be appreciated!

Problem #1: How to make a user chose a channel that that the bot sends the message in.

Problem #2: How to Make the bot send a message to all the servers that he is in.

Comment: Simply list the servers the bot is in, and let the user select the one it wants to send the message in. The rest is up to you to figure out. Don't hesitate to use [the documentation](https://discord.js.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to state all servers a bot is in, you can use a `forEach` method. Like so:

```
let servernames = "";

  bot.guilds.cache.forEach(guild => {
    servernames += `${guild.name}, `;
  });
  message.channel.send(`**${servernames.slice(0, servernames.length - 2)}**`)
```

However, if you are looking to send a message to every server regardless, you would still need a `forEach` method, simply join with the `.send` function. Example:

```
bot.guilds.cache.forEach(guild => {
    guild.defaultChannel.send("hi")
});
```

If you want to send a message to a specific channel, you need to `cache` it and find using the channel ID. Example:

```
let channelSend = bot.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.id === 'channel id here')
channelSend.send("hi")
```

Comment: I got one more question, I have a command where the user can set a channel for the message to be sent to, how can I get that channel to be sent the message that I want?
Thanks!

`const taggedChannel = message.mentions.channels.first();`

Comment: You can use the last method in my example, simply replace join args.